# How to Add Multiple Filters in Function.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm Using Genesis Framework on my website. I wanted to add Custom CSS Classes to my website's Navigation Menu and the Primary Sidebar.

To make this happen, I used the following code:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_nav-primary', 'themeprefix_add_css_attr' );
function themeprefix_add_css_attr( $attributes ) {

 $attributes['class'] .= ' toggle';

 return $attributes;

}
```

And a new class named "toggle" was added to Navigation Primary.

But When I added the code in Function.php for adding a new CSS class in Primary Sidebar as following, my website showed error 500.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_sidebar-primary', 'themeprefix_add_css_attr' );
function themeprefix_add_css_attr( $attributes ) {

 $attributes['class'] .= 'toggle2';

 return $attributes;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're defining two functions with the same name, which will cause an error. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_nav-primary', 'themeprefix_add_nav_css' );
function themeprefix_add_nav_css( $attributes ) {

 $attributes['class'] .= ' toggle';

 return $attributes;

}


add_filter( 'genesis_attr_sidebar-primary', 'themeprefix_add_sidebar_css' );
function themeprefix_add_sidebar_css( $attributes ) {

 $attributes['class'] .= 'toggle2';

 return $attributes;

}
```

Note that each filter is referencing a different function: `themeprefix_add_nav_css` and `themeprefix_add_sidebar_css`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help David. It worked perfectly :)